# MPI Scatter Array of Matrices Struct

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I have an array of type Matrix structs which the program got from user's input. I need to distribute the matrices to processes with OpenMPI. I tried using Scatter but I am quite confused about the arguments needed for the program to work (and also how to receive the data in each local arrays). Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define nil NULL
#define NMAX 100
#define DATAMAX 1000
#define DATAMIN -1000

typedef struct Matrix
{
    int mat[NMAX][NMAX]; // Matrix cells
    int row_eff;         // Matrix effective row
    int col_eff;         // Matrix effective column
} Matrix;

void init_matrix(Matrix *m, int nrow, int ncol)
{
    m->row_eff = nrow;
    m->col_eff = ncol;

    for (int i = 0; i < m->row_eff; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->col_eff; j++)
        {
            m->mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix input_matrix(int nrow, int ncol)
{
    Matrix input;
    init_matrix(&input, nrow, ncol);

    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &input.mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return input;
}

void print_matrix(Matrix *m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m->row_eff; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->col_eff; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", m->mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Get number of processes
    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // Get process rank
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // Get matrices from user inputs
    int kernel_row, kernel_col, num_targets, target_row, target_col;

    // reads kernel's row and column and initalize kernel matrix from input
    scanf("%d %d", &kernel_row, &kernel_col);
    Matrix kernel = input_matrix(kernel_row, kernel_col);

    // reads number of target matrices and their dimensions.
    // initialize array of matrices and array of data ranges (int)
    scanf("%d %d %d", &num_targets, &target_row, &target_col);
    Matrix *arr_mat = (Matrix *)malloc(num_targets * sizeof(Matrix));

    for (int i = 0; i < num_targets; i++)
    {
        arr_mat[i] = input_matrix(target_row, target_col);
    }

    // Get number of matrices per process
    int num_mat_per_proc = ceil(num_targets / size);

    // Init local matrices and scatter the global matrices
    Matrix *local_mats = (Matrix *)malloc(num_mat_per_proc * sizeof(Matrix));
    MPI_Scatter(arr_mat, sizeof(local_mats), MPI_BYTE, &local_mats, sizeof(local_mats), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        // Range arrays -> array of convolution results
        int arr_range[num_targets];
        printf("From master \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            print_matrix(&arr_mat[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("From slave %d = \n", rank);
        print_matrix(&local_mats[0]);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

So here's a few doubts I have about the current implementation:

1. Can I accept the input just like that or should I make it so that it only happens in rank 0?
2. How do I implement the scatter part and possibly using Scatterv because the amount of arrays might not be divisible to the number of processes?

Comment: sizeof(local_mats) is the size of a pointer (8 bytes if 64bits process) which is very unlikely what you want to use.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Which should I use to receive the data? How can I fix it?

Comment: why don't you take this opportunity to read the definition of `MPI_Scatter()`? note, the receive buffer argument is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I accept the input just like that or should I make it so that it
> only happens in rank 0?

No, You should use command line arguments or read from file as best practice.
If you want to use `scanf`, then use it inside `rank 0`. `STDIN` is forwarded to `rank 0` (this is not supported in standard as far as I know, But I guess this should work and will be implementation dependent)

> How do I implement the scatter part and possibly using Scatterv
> because the amount of arrays might not be divisible to the number of
> processes?

If you different size to send for different processes, then you should use `scatterv`.

`Scatter` Syntax:

```
MPI_Scatter(
    void* send_data,
    int send_count,
    MPI_Datatype send_datatype,
    void* recv_data,
    int recv_count,
    MPI_Datatype recv_datatype,
    int root,
    MPI_Comm communicator)
```

Your usage:

```
MPI_Scatter(arr_mat, sizeof(local_mats), MPI_BYTE, &local_mats, sizeof(local_mats), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Potential error points:

In `send_count`: Size to send (as ***Gilles Gouaillardet*** Pointed out in comments). `Sizeof(local_mats)` instead it should be `num_mat_per_proc * sizeof(Matrix)`.

`recv_count`: I believe size to receive should not be `sizeof(local_mats)`.

Since you use the same type (MPI_BYTES) for SEND and RECV, your `send_count == recv_count`

Comment: send and receive must have matching signatures. as a consequence, when `send_datatype == recv_datatype`, it is mandatory to have `send_count == recv_count`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, and the answers @j23! I did try on my own and it works with Scatter, but now I'm going to try to use Scatterv but I'm quite confused about how to create the displacement array of that case. Any pointers on this?

Comment: Displacement, in simple terms is the index in the source array from which your root process should start sending the send_count elements. Say for example, if you have `3` process, your source array (eg: `arr_mat`) is of size `20`, `displacement_array ={0,6, 12}`, `send_count_array={2,4,2}` and `root` process is `0`. Then `rank 0` will send `4` elements starting from index `6` of your source array (i.e from `arr_mat[6]` - `arr_mat[9]`). To `rank 2`, it sends `2` elements from index `12`  (i.e from `arr_mat[12]` - `arr_mat[13]`).

Comment: @Errata  This [link](https://www.rookiehpc.com/mpi/docs/mpi_scatterv.php) has a detailed explanation of the things mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @j23 Thanks! The scatter part is working now, gather awaits :D